# Can't get single checkbox to render in Flask WTF

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I've been searching a long time for examples on how to use checkboxes with Flask WTF, but it seems like either there are no example or there are really complex ones that involve a list of checkboxes.

I did find one example in Miguel's blog [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms), but I'm not able to get the checkbox to render. Here's what I did:

First off, the form class:

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    email = TextField("Email address", validators=[validators.required()])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[validators.required()])
    remember_me = BooleanField("Remember me", default = False)
    submit = SubmitField("Login")
```

And then in my template:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.email.label }}
        {{ form.email ( ** {'class' : 'form-control'} ) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.password.label }}
        {{ form.password ( ** {'class' : 'form-control'} ) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.remember_me }} Remember me
    </div>               
</form>
```

In the final output of the form, the checkbox is missing:

[image]

If I see the generated HTML, the field is just missing:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" action="/login" method="post">
                <div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1457326344##3036eeab4ffa39494ee92247925a30a88a69432f"><input id="next" name="next" type="hidden" value=""></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" type="password" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 Remember me             
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
            </div>          
            </form>
```

Curiously, if I try to add `{{ form.remember_me.label }}` to the template, I get an exception that `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'flask_security.forms.LoginForm object' has no attribute 'remember_me'`.

I also came across some solutions that mention custom widgets, but I'm really hoping to hear I won't have to go that route for a simple, single checkbox.

What am I doing wrong? If nothing, what's the shortest, most painless way to accomplish this?

**~~~~Update~~~~**

It looks like there's some weird behavior at work here. The field `form.remember` seems to produce a checkbox, and `form.remember.label` produces a default "Remember Me" label. Using any other name causes the aforesaid Exception to occur.

Comment: Looks correct to me - just checking, is the checkbox generated in the HTML source and simply not visible? Or is the checkbox HTML not generated at all?

Comment: @MattHealy I've updated my post with this info. The HTML isn't generated at all. Also using `form.remember_me.label` throws an exception (also mentioned in updated post).

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found my mistake. The import `from security import *` caused a flask-security template `LoginForm` to creep into my namespace, causing the weird behavior. I also needed to make some changes to my forms, importing the `Form` from `flask.ext.wtf` but the rest of the fields from `wtforms`. Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use `import *`.

Comment: @dirn Yeah, learnt it finally, the hard way. I thought * was more convenient. Now I know better.